# PHP validation always returns error/false in ajax even the conditions are true

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, validation

I have only two conditions.
If the `yourname` is empty return error
If the `email` is empty returns error
but I get error even if both are **not** empty.
I could not figure out why.

**My Form**

```
<form action="" method="post" name="contact-me" id="profile-update" class="requires-validation">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">  
        <i class="fas fa-key fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
        <div class="d-flex form-floating mb-0 flex-fill">    
            <input name="yourname" type="text" class="form-control name" placeholder="Type your name" >
            <label for="yourname" class="form-label">Your Name</label>
            <div class="yournameerror">Name field is valid!</div>
        </div>
    </div>    

    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">  
        <i class="fas fa-key fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
        <div class="d-flex form-floating mb-0 flex-fill">   
            <input name="email"  type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Type a valid email" >
            <label for="email" class="form-label">Your Email</label>
            <div class="emailerror">Name field is valid!</div>
        </div>    
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mx-4 mb-3 mb-lg-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="submit">Send message!</button>
    </div>
    <div id="nds_form_feedback"></div>
</form>
```

**Validation function**

```
<?php
function stack_update_validation_func(){
    $errors = array();
    $response = array();

    $yourname=$_POST['yourname'];
    $email=$_POST['email']; 

    if ($_POST['yourname'] == '')  {
        $errors['yourname'] = "Please enter your name"; 
    }

    if ((empty($_POST['email'])) ) {
        $errors['email'] = "Please enter your email";    
    } 

    $response['errors'] = $errors;

     if($errors !== '') {

        $response['success'] = false;
        $response['message'] = "Fail";

    } else {

        $reponse['success'] = true;
        $response['message'] = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Article added</div>";

         
    }
    header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
    echo json_encode($response);
    wp_die();
}
```

Getting that **JSON** response in this **Ajax**:

Please read the comments as well

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).on('click', '#submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = new FormData();

        data.append('action', 'stack_update_validation_func');   

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajax_url,
            data: data,
            contentType: false, //because I have a file upload feild as well
            processData: false, //because I have a file upload feild as well
            headers: {Accept : "application/json;charset=utf-8"},
            dataType: 'json',
            debug:true,
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.success) {
                   jQuery("#nds_form_feedback").html('Sucessfully Sent'); // if the form passes the validation this works fine
                }
                else {
                    alert("Not Uploaded"); // shows the popup if there is a validation error

                    jQuery.each(response.errors, function(key, val) {   
                        console.log(key); // returns the key like this https://prnt.sc/I4R0rNdRIF0o
                    }); 

                    console.log(response); // returns the json response in console 
                    
                    jQuery.each(response.errors, function(key, val) {   
                        jQuery('#profile-update [name="'+key+'"]').parent().find('.'+key+'error').html(val); 
                    });
                }
             }
       
    });
});
</script>
```

`console.log(response);` shows this

[image: console output]

but the issue is even `yourname` and `email` are filled correctly the error message is shown.
not sure what is wrong. please help.

Comment: `if($errors !== '')` will always be true, because `$errors` is an array. Use [!empty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) instead.

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST);` to see what the PHP fie is getting from the ajax. However, you're just sending the empty `new FormData();` with an action, you never append or grab the values from the form.

Comment: @aynber do you mean like this ? https://prnt.sc/BcQUF2ePdCSt - not getting anything in the console.
I removed values grabbing section first to check the response in ajax and validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method `stack_update_validation_func` there is a condition `if($errors !== '') {`. This condition will always be true because `$errors` will never be an empty string. It is initialized as empty array. So you should update the condition and your method could look like this:

```php
function stack_update_validation_func()
{
    $errors = array();
    $response = array();

    $yourname = $_POST['yourname'];
    $email = $_POST['email']; 

    if ($_POST['yourname'] == '')  {
        $errors['yourname'] = "Please enter your name"; 
    }

    if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $errors['email'] = "Please enter your email";    
    }

    $response['errors'] = $errors;

    if(!empty($errors)) {

        $response['success'] = false;
        $response['message'] = "Fail";

    } else {

        $response['success'] = true;
        $response['message'] = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Article added</div>";

    }
    header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
    echo json_encode($response);
    wp_die();
}
```

*Update*: Here is also the part of the JavaScript, that had to be updated:

```js
// instead of `var data = new FormData();`
var data = new FormData(document.getElementById('profile-update'));
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated like that and here is my method now https://prnt.sc/9EOBIxmLuKsn but I still see the same issue.

Comment: @FoolishCoder Sounds as if `$_POST['yourname'] == ''` and `empty($_POST['email'])` are `true`. What is the output of `var_dump($_POST); exit();`? Maybe `var data = new FormData();` in your JavaScript part clears the POST data. I think it should be `var data = new FormData(document.getElementById('profile-update'));`.

Comment: thank you so much. after adding ```var data = new FormData(document.getElementById('profile-update'));``` like this https://prnt.sc/YBDGQqUnPZvP I see the message ```<div class='alert alert-success'>Article added</div>``` in the console like this https://prnt.sc/uxVS7unpG2ux but before that I see this alert ```alert("Not Uploaded");``` but the other lines X marked in this screenshot https://prnt.sc/6zCSkCGaOOtl returns nothing. so if the validation passes I see success message and the alert but not other console prints from ```else``` condition in the Ajax

Comment: @FoolishCoder Oh, sorry, I didn't see the typing error in the PHP code at `$reponse['success'] = true;"`. There is missing an "s": `$response['success'] = true;"`.
I fixed it also in my answer above and added a notice for the `FormData` change.